# How to use c++ and objective-c together in XCode 4.2

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I had a trouble to combine c++ and objective-c together in developing a iphone app. I had a 3rd party library to use in the app. I had a plan to use c or c++ to wrap the library and then use objective-c to call it. After I had finished the class with c++, I had a trouble to use it in objective-c. Is there any sample code? Thanks.

in the objective-c head file. I write

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ZJTConstants.h"
#include "TTSAdapter.h"

class Adapter;
@interface ZJTVBlogViewController : UIViewController {
@private
    Adapter* adapter;
}
@end
```

and in the mm file, I write:

```
if (self) {
    adapter = Adapter::getInstance();
    // Custom initialization
}
```

Is it write?

Comment: It seems you are indeed using `.mm` file, so, what's the trouble? you have not told us what problem you are facing.

Comment: It says that there are some compilation error, so I was wondering if there's anything wrong in the syntax.

Comment: Have you fixed it? If not, just precise what "some compilation error" is.

Comment: Thanks, it is not fixed yet. But the reason is that a library file in the project do not have i386 version which is needed in the simulator compilation. I was searching for one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Calling C++ code from Objective-C code involves ending your file with
>   .mm (instead of .m) so that the Objective-C++ compiler will be used.
>
> This compiler can understand both C++ and Objective-C.
>
> In other words, the ObjC++ compiler lets you put C++ code directly in
>   Objective-C methods, and vice versa.

Take a look at [Cocoa_With_Carbon_or_CPP example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Cocoa_With_Carbon_or_CPP/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000383-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_7) and [Strategies for Using C++ in Objective-C Projects (and vice versa)](http://www.philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects) article .

Answer (score 8):

In XCode there is a flag to compile all files as Objective-C++. I've used it to compile huge C++ libraries into iOS programs.

If you look at the "Build Settings" there is a place written "Compile Sources As". There is a dropdown menu there where you can select Objective-C++. In the clang/gcc commandline I think it is "-x objective-c++".

Comment: Size doesn't matter What you have to do is just change change the extension to .mm of to class that containing C++ code ...

Comment: @HikmatKhan What I was  suggesting is that sometimes renaming files, especially in big (multiperson) projects is not really an option.

Comment: @kevlar If you look at the "Build Settings" there is a place written "Compile Sources As". There is a dropdown menu there where you can select Objective-C++. In clang I think it is "-x objective-c++"

Answer (score 6):

Just rename your file to have an extension `.mm` instead of `.m`.

To mix C++ code with Objective-C code, you will need [Objective-C++](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ObjectiveCPlusPlus) compiler.
XCode by default compiles `.m` files with Objective-C compiler and `.mm` ones with Objective-C++ one.